# How to iterate through a Component's Children in Typescript React?

Tags: typescript, reactjs, tsx

How do I iterate through a React component's children in Typescript tsx?

The following would be valid jsx:

```
public render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {React.Children.map(this.props.children, x => x.props.foo)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

However, in Typescript, the type of x is `React.ReactElement<any>` so I have no access to props. Is there some kind of casting that I need to do?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using `any` should generally be avoided as you're losing the type info.

Instead use `React.ReactElement<P>` in the function parameter type:

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child: React.ReactElement<ChildPropTypes>) => child.props.bar)
```

Comment: And if you want the grandchildren, they're at `child.props.children` :)

Answer (score 22):

> However, in Typescript, the type of x is React.ReactElement so I have no access to props. Is there some kind of casting that I need to do?

Yes. Also prefer the term `assertion`. A quick one:

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, x => (x as any).props.foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, {FC, Children, isValidElement } from "react"



 const MyComponent: FC = ({children}) => {
    // define component logic
    return ( 
    // children is a prop that passed to the component
    // second arg is a callback
    { Children.map(children, child => {
              // if child is a valid element, we can set attributes
              // you might need to add attributes dynamically
              if (isValidElement(child)) {
                return {
                  ...child,
                  props: {
                    ...child.props,
                    className:"Add className here"
                  }
                }
               }
              // if element is not valid just return child
              return child
    })
```